# Having problems with quoting a string for a command line argument

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a command line argument for Process. This is my string as it is coded. I set the variable taskName to "This is a test"

```
     p.StartInfo.Arguments += " /RU " + "" + userName + "" + " /RP " + "" + domainPassword + "" + "  /TN " +
                                   "\"" + taskName + "\"" + " /TR " + "" + task.InputFileName + "" + " /ST " +
                                   "" + startTime + "" + " /SD " + "" + startDate + "";
```

when i run it, this is what i get for /TN.

/TN \"this is a test\"

Why am i getting the backslashes. I just want it to say  /TN "This is a test"

Comment: Can you do a `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(p.StartInfo.Arguments);` and also paste its output here (possibly removing private info such as paths)? That would make it easier to recognize what is actually passed.

Comment: Aside: with that many string concatenations, I suggest using something like `String.Format` to increase readability.  This may make it easier to find where the bugs exist.

Comment: Where do you see the backslashes? In Debugger window? (normal) in a Trace? In ConsoleWriteLine()?

Answer (score 0):

This gave me the expected result you are looking for which is no different than what you have.

```
string taskName = "This is a test";
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.Arguments = " /TN " + "\"" + taskName + "\"";

Console.WriteLine(process.StartInfo.Arguments);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because there are spaces in the TaskName, you need to put " around them so that the command like will see them as one argument, not as many (4 for This is a test)

To embed a " in a C# string you escape it with a :

```
Console.WriteLine("output: \"");
output: "
```

If you tries:

```
Console.WriteLine(""");
```

You'd get a syntax error because the second " closes the first, and the third " open a new set which isn't closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using string literal of c#, check it out here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

e.g.

string hello = @"World said ""Hello"" to me";
If you this print hello variable if will show output:

Joe said "Hello" to me

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining how/why this solution works.  Perhaps you could include an example.  As it stands, this link to documentation is not very helpful.